# How to create common Header and footer for all child pages in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using reactjs in an application and I need to add Registration page.

I want a parent layout with common header and footer page.

When anyone 'll click Sign Up button,same common header and footer 'll be placed.

```
-------------------Header.js------------------

import React from 'react';
import { fade,makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
// import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
// import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import './App.css'; 
/* AppBar*/
//import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import MoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';
/*App bar */

// import  ImgMediaCard from './ImgMediaCard';

// import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
// import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';

// import DemoCarousel from './MCarousel';

// var gridListStyle = {  
//     marginLeft: "40px"
//   };

  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    grow: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
      display: 'none',
      [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        display: 'block',
      },
    },
    search: {
      position: 'relative',
      borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
      },
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
      marginLeft: 0,
      width: '100%',
      [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
        width: 'auto',
      },
    },
    searchIcon: {
      width: theme.spacing(7),
      height: '100%',
      position: 'absolute',
      pointerEvents: 'none',
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    inputRoot: {
      color: 'inherit',
    },
    inputInput: {
      padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 7),
      transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
      width: '100%',
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        width: 200,
      },
    },
    sectionDesktop: {
      display: 'none',
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        display: 'flex',
      },
    },
    sectionMobile: {
      display: 'flex',
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        display: 'none',
      },
    }  
  }));
  /*end App bar work*/
  const useGridStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    paper: {
      // padding: theme.spacing(2),
      // textAlign: 'center',
      // color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
  }));

function Header({ history }) {
    const Gridclasses = useGridStyles();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    handleMobileMenuClose();
  };

  const handleMobileMenuOpen = event => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const onRegisterClick = () => {
    debugger;    
      history.push('/Register');      
 };

  const menuId = 'primary-search-account-menu';
  const renderMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      id={menuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  const mobileMenuId = 'primary-search-account-menu-mobile';
  const renderMobileMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      id={mobileMenuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMobileMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem>   
      <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" />    
     </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>     
        <IconButton aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
          <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
            <MailIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Messages</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton aria-label="show 11 new notifications" color="inherit">
          <Badge badgeContent={11} color="secondary">
            <NotificationsIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Notifications</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="account of current user"
          aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          color="inherit"
        >
          <AccountCircle />
        </IconButton>
        <p>Profile</p>
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );
  return (

  <Paper className={Gridclasses.paper}>

      <div className={classes.grow}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
            Shopping Center
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.grow} />
          <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>          
          <IconButton  aria-label="" color="inherit" onClick={onRegisterClick}> Sign Up             
            </IconButton> 
            <IconButton aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                <MailIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="show 17 new notifications" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={17} color="secondary">
                <NotificationsIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              edge="end"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls={menuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.sectionMobile}>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="show more"
              aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {renderMobileMenu}
      {renderMenu}
       </div>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default Header;




-------------------Register.js----------------

import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import FilledInput from '@material-ui/core/FilledInput';
import OutlinedInput from '@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Visibility from '@material-ui/icons/Visibility';
import VisibilityOff from '@material-ui/icons/VisibilityOff';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  withoutLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  textField: {
    width: 200,
  },
}));

function RegisterBuyer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    amount: '',
    password: '',
    weight: '',
    weightRange: '',
    showPassword: false,
  });

  const handleChange = prop => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    setValues({ ...values, showPassword: !values.showPassword });
  };

  const handleMouseDownPassword = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div>
        <TextField
          label="With normal TextField"
          id="standard-start-adornment"
          className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">Kg</InputAdornment>,
          }}
        />
        <FormControl className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.withoutLabel, classes.textField)}>
          <Input
            id="standard-adornment-weight"
            value={values.weight}
            onChange={handleChange('weight')}
            endAdornment={<InputAdornment position="end">Kg</InputAdornment>}
            aria-describedby="standard-weight-helper-text"
            inputProps={{
              'aria-label': 'weight',
            }}
          />
          <FormHelperText id="standard-weight-helper-text">Weight</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">Password</InputLabel>
          <Input
            id="standard-adornment-password"
            type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange('password')}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.margin}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-amount">Amount</InputLabel>
          <Input
            id="standard-adornment-amount"
            value={values.amount}
            onChange={handleChange('amount')}
            startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </div>
      <div>
        <TextField
          label="With normal TextField"
          id="filled-start-adornment"
          className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">Kg</InputAdornment>,
          }}
          variant="filled"
        />
        <FormControl className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)} variant="filled">
          <FilledInput
            id="filled-adornment-weight"
            value={values.weight}
            onChange={handleChange('weight')}
            endAdornment={<InputAdornment position="end">Kg</InputAdornment>}
            aria-describedby="filled-weight-helper-text"
            inputProps={{
              'aria-label': 'weight',
            }}
          />
          <FormHelperText id="filled-weight-helper-text">Weight</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)} variant="filled">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-adornment-password">Password</InputLabel>
          <FilledInput
            id="filled-adornment-password"
            type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange('password')}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                  edge="end"
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.margin} variant="filled">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-adornment-amount">Amount</InputLabel>
          <FilledInput
            id="filled-adornment-amount"
            value={values.amount}
            onChange={handleChange('amount')}
            startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </div>
      <div>
        <TextField
          label="With normal TextField"
          id="outlined-start-adornment"
          className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">Kg</InputAdornment>,
          }}
          variant="outlined"
        />
        <FormControl className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)} variant="outlined">
          <OutlinedInput
            id="outlined-adornment-weight"
            value={values.weight}
            onChange={handleChange('weight')}
            endAdornment={<InputAdornment position="end">Kg</InputAdornment>}
            aria-describedby="outlined-weight-helper-text"
            inputProps={{
              'aria-label': 'weight',
            }}
            labelWidth={0}
          />
          <FormHelperText id="outlined-weight-helper-text">Weight</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)} variant="outlined">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-password">Password</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            id="outlined-adornment-password"
            type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange('password')}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                  edge="end"
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
            labelWidth={70}
          />
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.margin} variant="outlined">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-amount">Amount</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            id="outlined-adornment-amount"
            value={values.amount}
            onChange={handleChange('amount')}
            startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>}
            labelWidth={60}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}   

export default  Register

-------------------Index.js-------------------
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';
import Header from './Header.js'
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import RegisterBuyer from './RegisterBuyer';

ReactDOM.render(   
    <Router>
       <Header />
    <Switch>
  <Route path="/RegisterBuyer" component={RegisterBuyer} />
  <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
   , document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm a newbie with react. What should I do in my code?

I've grabbed the example code for a menus and cards from here: https://material-ui.com

```
Application built with

{
  "react": "16.13.0", 
  "react-dom": "^16.13.0", 
  "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
  "redux": "^4.0.4"
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5"
}
```

The problem i face is getting an error in following function:

```
const onRegisterClick = () => {
    debugger;    
      history.push('/Register');      
 };
```

above function is displaying below error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:306
executeDispatch
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:389
executeDispatchesInOrder
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:414
executeDispatchesAndRelease
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3278
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3287
forEachAccumulated
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3259
runEventsInBatch
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3304
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3514
handleTopLevel
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3558
batchedEventUpdates$1
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21902
batchedEventUpdates
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:1060
dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3568
attemptToDispatchEvent
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4267
dispatchEvent
/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4189
unstable_runWithPriority
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11061
discreteUpdates$1
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21918
discreteUpdates
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:1071
dispatchDiscreteEvent
/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4168
Output: SignUp component should be displayed in Layout (Parent) with same common Header and Footer.

I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not solve/explain the issue well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've updated this to align with your "master" and "child" page concept.

---

React is component based, so any components that you want to render next to or around a set of other components should be structured in that way.

For example, you want to render your `Header` component above the rest of the page content. Therefore it makes sense to render your `Header` **next to** the page content:

```
const MasterPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <ChildPage />
        </>
    )
}

const ChildPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          {/* ...child page content goes here... */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here we define two components inside our `MasterPage` component. The `Header` is rendered above the `ChildPage` component.

The `ChildPage` component contains the contents of the child page, which can be whatever you like. No matter what you render inside `ChildPage`, the `Header` will always be rendered regardless.

This means you don't have to repeatedly render the header in every single child page component.

The `<>` and `</>` tags are short-hand for [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), which means you don't have to wrap your `Header` and `ChildPage` in an extra `div`, but you could just as easily write:

```
<div>
  <Header />
  <ChildPage />
</div>
```

You can do the same thing for your `Footer`:

```
<>
  <Header />
  <ChildPage />
  <Footer />
</>
```

---

The error you are seeing is because you need to import `history`. Currently it is `undefined` so you're trying to push to an undefined array.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am not sure you have fully understand my question or not. i was something like master and child page relationship. each child page like register 'll be added with same header and footer only content will be change for each page

Comment: I've updated my answer. The only difference is the semantics. Your "Master" page is just a wrapper around the child page, it's the same concept.

Comment: Yes i got the point. thank you JMadalaine.  In App file , i just added {history} and push was working fine but now why not in Header({history}) works like App ?

Comment: You have to add the `history` import in every file that needs it. Imports do not get shared across files.

Comment: Dear i am using hooks in pure functions not classes.

Comment: Regardless of whether you are using function components or class components, you still need to import `history` in every file that uses it. It is not related to the type of components.

Comment: import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"; const cushistory = createBrowserHistory(); function Header(history={cushistory}) but same error

Comment: `Header(history={cushistory})` is not valid. As this problem is off-topic (your original question was about rendering a header component on all pages) please post another question about the issues you are having with using history.